# Creating unobtrusive overlay for arbitrary html document

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, overlay

I'm trying to create an overlay that attaches itself to an existing DOM node and covers its entire content area. This should work regardless of whether this node is the body of the page or some deeply nested div. It's key that the layout of the page that I am overlaying should not change. Eventually, my code will run as a browser extension on top of existing html pages.

I am encountering a problem in the very simple case where I am trying to overlay a page with text (or anything that takes space) directly nested within the document body. I have no choice but to append my overlay div as another child node of the body and set its position to absolute and its width/height to 100%. Of course, in the case where the body is statically positioned (default), my div will size to the viewport and not the body's content. If content overflows, my overlay won't cover all of it :\.

All other answers suggest setting the position of the parent div (the body in my case) to define it as the positioning context. I can't do this, however. Changing the position of the document body to 'relative', for example, could change the layout of the content of the body, and defeats the purpose of an unobtrusive overlay. What to do?

Extension-specific suggestions are welcome. For reference, the extension will be for Chrome.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dt9dauwt/) with a hypothetical page that I have to overlay. Note that although the original page is strangely formatted, my overlay cannot change it.

```
<body>
  <style>
    .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%
        /*some magic I am unaware of*/
    }
  </style>
  <!-- begin original document (stupid hypothetical scenario) -->
  <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:red;">
    <!-- this div is part of the original html document I want to overlay.
    It should behave as it did originally, i.e size to the viewport of the document-->
  </div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam id tellus vehicula, tincidunt est fermentum, hendrerit dui. Nullam lacinia, justo sed porta hendrerit, nisl quam blandit nunc, ut imperdiet nibh metus in ante. Pellentesque viverra egestas
  nulla eu dictum. Aliquam ac accumsan leo. Integer ut tellus odio. Duis blandit venenatis venenatis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum vel lorem egestas, tincidunt sem vel, venenatis
  ipsum. Donec vitae blandit nibh. Curabitur cursus nunc arcu, id tempor massa gravida ut. Integer vulputate libero in placerat vestibulum. Duis quis turpis vel lectus venenatis rhoncus. Sed congue est consequat, dapibus odio sit amet, sollicitudin arcu.
  Praesent hendrerit massa velit, vel pretium erat viverra quis. Proin non enim facilisis, venenatis dolor ut, dapibus nulla. Morbi vestibulum mollis felis ut venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
  mus. Ut mollis velit nulla, et tristique sapien auctor eu. Phasellus tincidunt mauris elit, vel fringilla leo consectetur a. Vivamus a porta magna. Mauris hendrerit leo eget sapien aliquet dignissim. Nunc id sem est. Integer sed lacus est. Nulla sit
  amet sapien et ex aliquam malesuada quis vel eros. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus turpis ligula, elementum sit amet sapien nec, malesuada fringilla nibh. Duis euismod, purus semper viverra aliquam, ligula sem
  vehicula mi, sit amet cursus mauris augue vel enim. Donec lacinia diam quis sapien laoreet vulputate in eu est. Proin consequat, ex vitae molestie pellentesque, libero purus pellentesque arcu, id porttitor orci sem a lectus. Morbi mattis in metus quis
  euismod. Nam arcu augue, imperdiet eu felis eu, rhoncus facilisis lectus. Nullam placerat, tortor non tincidunt tristique, purus magna cursus leo, vitae sagittis odio turpis sodales nisi. Nullam vehicula erat nisl, ac venenatis massa rutrum sed. Mauris
  massa tortor, volutpat vel nisl a, consectetur molestie sapien. Quisque eu elit nulla. Praesent at eros vehicula, lobortis purus quis, efficitur velit. Donec eget faucibus nisl. Praesent pharetra mattis porta. Donec volutpat lacinia dui non maximus.
  Vivamus eu sodales leo. Ut eu ipsum scelerisque, consectetur turpis condimentum, malesuada elit. Proin tincidunt mauris metus, eu tincidunt ex ultrices ut. Sed sollicitudin leo nunc, in pharetra ligula egestas ut. Etiam suscipit eget ligula ut convallis.
  Ut tempus tellus id ultrices rutrum. Nam accumsan fermentum metus, tristique gravida eros ultricies eget. Integer tortor diam, posuere ut ornare quis, bibendum ut tellus. Maecenas imperdiet lacus vitae felis viverra, nec dignissim lacus volutpat. Curabitur
  et elit vehicula ipsum luctus tempor et sed enim. Fusce ultrices eget ante nec consectetur. Donec commodo nunc eget diam tristique, at euismod nisl commodo. Fusce felis neque, vulputate ut tincidunt sed, commodo in risus. Quisque sed magna sodales tortor
  condimentum aliquam. Phasellus mattis justo eget diam tincidunt luctus. Cras pharetra ultrices sem, sed sollicitudin purus feugiat sed. Vivamus vitae tempor velit.
  <!-- end original document -->
  <div class='overlay'>
    <!-- this div is my overlay. It should size to the content of the document body, not the viewport. Careful setting the body's position to relative, the other div will change!-->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: *" If content overflows, my overlay won't cover all of it :\."* - Yeah, I think that's gonna be a hard one to solve. On the other hand, making something that covers the entire content area shouldn't be that hard, but I assume you mean it should *tightly* cover that area, in other words, it should be no bigger than it needs to be to cover that area.

Comment: That's right. As in, I don't want to have an overlay that's fixed. I want an overlay that is the size of the node in question and that follows its scrolling/resizing behavior.

Comment: Can we size and position the overlay with jQuery?

Comment: The reason I think it's hard, is because content can be rendered outside of the element. I'm not even sure if you can get the right dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're best off appending one element to the body (unless you have access to some higher stacked element available to extensions) and simply use the `element.getClientBoundingRect()` to obtain the position and dimensions.

```js
function applyStyle(element, styles) {
  for (var key in styles) {
    element.style[key] = styles[key];
  }
}

var overlay = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
    indicator = overlay.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));

//  apply the styles
applyStyle(overlay, {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  zIndex: 2147483647,  //  it doesn't get higher than this
  pointerEvents: 'none'
});

applyStyle(indicator, {
  position: 'absolute',
  border: '1px dotted red',
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)'
});
      

window.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  var bound = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();

  applyStyle(indicator, {
    top: bound.top + 'px',
    left: bound.left + 'px',
    width: bound.width + 'px',
    height: bound.height + 'px'
  });
});
```

```css
.foo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 200px auto 0;
  max-height: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class=foo>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ut nibh dapibus tellus varius tristique vitae id elit. Fusce vestibulum neque a scelerisque pellentesque. Vestibulum eu odio risus. Aliquam id tellus in mauris sollicitudin vestibulum. Aenean vestibulum et massa vel dapibus. Pellentesque eu lectus odio. Aliquam vitae fermentum mauris. Pellentesque feugiat sem vel dolor imperdiet tempor.
</div>

<div class=bar>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ut nibh dapibus tellus varius tristique vitae id elit. Fusce vestibulum neque a scelerisque pellentesque. Vestibulum eu odio risus. Aliquam id tellus in mauris sollicitudin vestibulum. Aenean vestibulum et massa vel dapibus. Pellentesque eu lectus odio. Aliquam vitae fermentum mauris. Pellentesque feugiat sem vel dolor imperdiet tempor.
</div>
```

The bits of "trickery" in here involve:

- using the maximum z-index *combined* with the overlay element being the last element within `<body>` makes it *nearly* impossible for any page to rise above it
- the little known `getBoundingClientRect` treasure
- `pointer-events: none` css, removing the interactivity from the overlay element (simply add `pointer-events: auto` on the indicator to re-enable)

As you are targeting one specific browser and a (evergreen) modern one, I don't think you should use jQuery. You don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether jQuery is an option but I couldn't resist... Here's how you could use jQuery to style your overlay

```
var $thingToOverlay = $('#someDivOrWhatever');   // use $(document) for whole page
var $overlay = $('.overlay');

var getMaxZ = function($elements){
    var z;
    return Math.max.apply(null, $elements.map(function(){        
        return isNaN(z = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"), 10)) ? 0 : z;      
    }));
};

$overlay.css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'box-sizing': 'border-box',
    'background-color': 'red',
    'height': $thingToOverlay.height(),
    'width': $thingToOverlay.width(),
    'top': $thingToOverlay.offset().top,    // don't use this for whole page (document), just set to 0
    'left': $thingToOverlay.offset().left,   // ditto
    'z-index': getMaxZ($overlay.siblings())   // assuming overlay is last on page, no need to +1
});
```

This will obviously need some logic around it depending on whether the overlay needs to cover the whole page or just a div but you get the idea?

Comment: Don't forget zIndex.

Comment: OP had `.overlay` as last div on page so z-index shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Other elements can have an explicit z-index.